# python abspath returning path twice

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to get an absolute path of a relative path string with python but it keeps printing the path twice. For example:

```
self.path = 'Users/abdulahmad/Desktop'
self.actual_path = os.path.abspath(self.path)
print self.actual_path
```

my console prints

```
/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop
```

and if I change the path to:

```
self.path = 'Desktop'
```

my console prints:

```
/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/Desktop
```

shouldn't it just print `/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop` in both cases?

Comment: You should use `'/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop'` instead of `'Users/abdulahmad/Desktop'`.

Comment: @GustavoBezerra isn't that the whole point of using `os.path.abspath`? so it can give me the correct full path? otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question at all

Comment: `os.path.abspath` gives you the absolute path when the path is relative to the *current* directory, not `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the current working directory is `/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop`.

If you write for example `path/to/file` it means relative to current working directory and relative to `/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop` it would mean `/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/path/to/file`.

If you read the python3 manual it actually shows an implementation of `os.abspath(path)` as being the same as `os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path))`. This can be used to get a path relative to arbitrarily provided path. (It also shows that you actually basically joins the current working directory and the supplied (relative) path)

Comment: I see.. is there a way to get the abs path relative to a path string that I provide?

Comment: Yes, to get `path` relative to `base_path` do `os.path.normpath(os.path.join(base_path, path))`.